# First list item is randomly changing

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a problem with the Android `ArrayAdapter`. The first item in the list is not in alphabetical order. If I scroll down, and scroll back up, it changes to a different list item.

Why is the list not working?

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SQLHelper helper = new SQLHelper(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_selector_listview,
            container, false);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.song_item, listArtists(db));

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

public List<String> listArtists(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " 
            + SQLHelper.artistCol
            + " FROM " 
            + SQLHelper.libraryTable 
            + " ORDER BY "
            + SQLHelper.artistCol, 
            null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int artistIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLHelper.artistCol);
        artists.add(cursor.getString(artistIndex));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return artists;
}
```

Comment: Similar symptoms are usually caused by bugs in a custom adapter `getView()` but since you're using stock `ArrayAdapter` that is not the case. Could you post the `song_item` layout?

Comment: @laalto I've just this second realised it was because of null values within my SQLite table. I re-created the table, and made sure no null values were added, and it seems to have worked. I can't answer my question for another 8 hours, so I thought I would post here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in ArrayAdapter. You may create custom adapter and make it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your list view correctly. Remove animated lay change, ddrawable cash etc.